# A question on continuous map from mobius strip to disc

Tags: general-topology

We know that every continuous map from mobius strip to disc has self-intersecting. Here by self-intersecting is the graph of map for example $(x,f(x))$ as a surface intersect itself. My question is:

> **Question:** Is it possible that a continuous map from mobius strip to disc has exactly one self-intersection point?

Comment: Define "self-intersection point". Usually the term "has self-intersection" is just another way of saying "$f$ is not injective".